# Check if meta key value already exists

Tags: metabox, post-meta

Let's say that I have few posts with meta key "videoid". Value of that meta key is different for every post (and has to be different). When adding new post, how can I check if videoid with that exact value already exist for some older posts? I used this as a refference for adding custom meta box to admin area of WP: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Which plugin did you use? Please [edit] your question and add a link. Sidenote: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to say that I used that code (on that link), in my own plugin. Never mind, deleted that part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do a query with `WP_Query` using the [Custom Field parameters (`meta_query`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) to look for posts with the meta key and the value - exemplary code:

```
 // args to query for your key
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'videoid',
           'value' => $new_posts_videoid  // for example: '111'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids'
 );
 // perform the query
 $vid_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 $vid_ids = $vid_query->posts;

 // do something if the meta-key-value-pair exists in another post
 if ( ! empty( $vid_ids ) ) {
     // do your stuff
 }
```

There is no need to use `query_post()` - see: 
[When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755)
. If you need a complete array of post objects, not just the ids, remove `'fields' => 'ids'`.

Comment: $q_vid does not return just a list of ID's, it's the entire wp_query object. See my answer for fix

Comment: true, thanks, I'd appreciate it if you fix it by [editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/121166/edit) my answer next time @JordanLejuwaan

Answer (score 2):

ialocin's answer incorrectly states that the wp_query stored as a variable would just spit out an array of ID's. Instead it gives the whole WP_Query object, so you have to use ->posts to get that array of post ID's.

```
// args to query for your key
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'YOUR_META_FIELD_NAME',
           'value' => '111'
       )
   ),
   'fields' => 'ids'
 );
 // perform the query
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 $duplicates = $query->posts;

 // do something if the key-value-pair exists in another post
 if ( ! empty( $duplicates ) ) {
     // do your stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or wrap it up in a function:

```
function meta_value_exists($your_meta_value) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'meta_key'     => 'your_meta_field',
        'meta_value'   => $your_meta_value,
    );
    $current_post = get_posts($args);
    if( $current_post ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So then you could just check on your meta value:

```
$video_id = 1234;
if(meta_value_exists($video_id){
   // do something if exists
} else {
   // do something if not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'videoid',
            'value' => $_POST['videoid']
        )
    )
);

$videoQuery = new WP_Query( $args ); 

if ( $videoQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $videoQuery->have_posts() ) : 
            $videoQuery->the_post(); ?>
    echo "<h3 class='post-title'>" . the_title() . "</h3>";
    endwhile; 
    endif;
```